# How to write struct that has pointer in it

Tags: c, pointers, struct, fwrite

I have a struct that has a pointer to another struct:

```
typedef struct _contacts
{
    Contact *elements;
    int length;
    int capacity;
} Contacts;
```

and this is my Contact struct:

```
typedef struct _contact
{
    int id;
    char firstName[NAME_SIZE];
    char lastName[NAME_SIZE];
    char address[ADDRESS_SIZE];
    char email[EMAIL_SIZE];
    char phoneNumber[NUMBER_SIZE];
    char homeNumber[NUMBER_SIZE];
} Contact;
```

When I try to write Contacts on a binary file using fwrite,

```
Contacts *contacts = newEmptyContacts();
// do something with contacts...
fwrite(contacts, sizeof(Contacts), 1, file);
```

it writes a pointer to Contact, which I don't want.

How can I store each element of Contacts along side length and capacity members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that your code writes a pointer to the file, that's simply what you're asking your code to do. Instead of writing the `contacts` structure you need to write the *elements* of `contacts`. You also need to write the number of contacts somehow, so the code that will read the file knows how many contacts to read:

Assuming `length` is the actual number of contacts and `capacity` is the available storage space, your code should roughly be something like this:

```
Contacts *contacts = newEmptyContacts();
// do something with contacts...

// write the number of contacts and capacity to the file    
fwrite(&contacts.length, sizeof(contacts.length), 1, file);
fwrite(&contacts.capacity, sizeof(contacts.capacity), 1, file);

// write all contacts to the file
fwrite(contacts.elements, sizeof(Contact), contacts.length, file);
```

The read code could be something like this:

```
int length;
int capacity;

// read the length from the file    
fread(&length, sizeof(length), 1, file);

// read the capacity from the file    
fread(&capacity, sizeof(capacity), 1, file);

// allocate a Contacts structure for length contacts
Contacts *contacts = newContacts(capacity);  

// read length contacts from the file
fread(contacts.elements, sizeof(Contact), length, file);
contacts.length = length;
...

Contacts *newContacts(int capacity)
{
  Contacts *contacts = malloc(capacity* sizeof(*contacts));
  contacts->capacity = capacity;
  contacts->length = 0;
  return contacts;
}
```

**Disclaimer**: this is untested code, it may contain errors and there is no error checking at all, but you should get the idea.